# Test if a schema belongs to a particular database

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, sed, awk

I asked a similar question however the answer seems to be giving me some problems. My overall goal is to be able to remove a certain record from a particular database.

databases.txt contains:

```
class grades
```

schema.txt contains:

```
grades name test1 test2 test3
```

class.db contains:

```
Nick 79 84 85
You 24 83 52
Her 84 98 55
```

Desired input would be:

```
./del.sh class test2 84
```

My goal is to remove any lines with '84' within the db that test2 and class belong to.

I validate the existence of the database by using:

```
awk '{ print $1 }' databases.txt >> temp.txt

if  grep -Fxq $1 temp.txt 
then
    rm temp.txt
    touch temp.txt
else 
    echo "Database name error. Exiting."
    rm temp.txt
    exit 1
fi
```

My current problem is validating that test2 belongs to the schema which belongs to the database entered by the user, and if that field does not exist within that schema print an error message.

A previous response I was given was:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}a[$2]~/$2/{print $0}' schemas.txt databases.txt
```

However, it does not seem to really check properly and it prints the databases file which is unnecessary. My code for removing records is kind of shotty right now aswell:

```
var=$(grep -c $3 $1.db)
delrec=$3

echo "There were" $var "records deleted from the $1 database."
sed -i "/$delrec/d" $1.db
```

Comment: Seriously, I wouldn't use scripts/sed/awk for such a task. Perl or Python would be my choices. Doing input validation, escaping, quoting, and similar things are rather awkward (PITA) in scripting tools.

Comment: I agree, however I do need to write this in a shell script. =/

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/ksh
SchemaRef="`sed -n \"/$1 / s/^[^ ]* //p\"`"
if [ -z ${SchemaRef}" ]
  then
    return 1
  fi

FieldNr="`sed -n \"/^${SchemaRef} / s/ /\
/gp\" schema.txt | grep -n | sed -n \"/:$2$/ s/^[^:]:/\1/p\"`"
if [ -z ${FieldNr}" ]
  then
    return 2
  fi

FieldBefore=$(( ${FieldNr} - 1 ))
sed -n "/\([^ ]\{1,\} \)\{${FieldBefore}\}$3 / !p" $1.db
```

something like that (no unix here to validate). If used under linux (or with GNU sed) add --posix to sed parameter